# Netgear RND2000 diskless NAS, is it really that noisy?

Tags: nas, noise

I have just received from Amazon the [Netgear RND2000 Diskless NAS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Netgear-ReadyNAS-RND2000-Storage-Solution/dp/B001O35S7M) (cough..won on [SU contest](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1342/super-contest-winners-week-1)).
I don't have Sata Hard disks at home so I just turned it ON to check the boot.
After a loud noise at start, fan goes down but stays louder than a standard pc.
From your experience, is that because it is not running in normal mode (without HD) or is it really that noisy?

**Edit**:

I've mounted the Sata Harddisk and I've got to say that this NAS is pretty quiet.

Comment: Isn't there a saying about looking gift horses in the mouth? ;)

Comment: @JNK hahahah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [feedback at newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822122029), it sounds like it is a fairly noisy device (pun intended).

Otherwise feedback is good, so you got your money's worth for sure!

Comment: Found this [comment](http://www.buzzillions.com/reviews/netgear-readynas-duo-rnd2000-nas-server-reviews): The ReadyNAS is very quiet. When it first was formatting the drives the fan ran at full speed and was noisy but then they slowed down to 1500 RPM and you hardly can hear it

Answer (score 1):

I don't have one of these, but a lot of those enclosures have really small fans.  If you buy a larger, higher quality fan, you won't hear it nearly as much.  Usually a little work with a Dremel does the trick.

Also, depending on your drives you might not need the fan at all.  This isn't likely though... drives seem to run hotter and hotter these days.